# srun: error: Ignoring conflicting option "x11" in plugin "x11"

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When I am trying to get an interactive session on a gpu node, I got the following error. Does anyone know what the error means and how it will affect my interactive session? Thank you.

```
srun: error: Ignoring conflicting option "x11" in plugin "x11"
```